# DDL Trigger at Database level

Tags: oracle, plsql, ddl, database-trigger

I've created the DB level trigger to audit the DDL actions, however its getting fired only in oracle 12c, not in oracle 11g. Even after changing parameter 'enable_ddl_logging' value to TRUE, its not getting fired. Can someone let me know, why its not working in Oracle 11g ?

Below is the DDL trigger:

```
create or replace trigger audit_ddl_trg after ddl on database 
begin
    insert into schema.audit_ddl(ddl_date, osuser,current_user,host,terminal,owner,type,name,sysevent)
    values(
      sysdate,
      sys_context('USERENV','OS_USER') ,
      sys_context('USERENV','CURRENT_USER') ,
      sys_context('USERENV','HOST') ,
      sys_context('USERENV','TERMINAL') ,
      ora_dict_obj_owner,
      ora_dict_obj_type,
      ora_dict_obj_name,
      ora_sysevent
    );
    exception when others then 
    raise;
 end;
/
```

Thanks,
Vishnu

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel?  Why not just use the AUDIT capability that oracle has already built?

Comment: @EdStevens, Please share the documentation link also.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai - sorry, I guess I expected the OP to be able to google 'oracle audit', or some such.  There are multiple points of reference, but the two _starting_ points would be the relevant sections from the _2-Day + Security Guide_ (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDPSG/GUID-BF747771-01D1-4BFB-8489-08988E1181F6.htm#TDPSG50000 ) and the _Database Security Guide_. (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/part_6.htm#DBSEG006)

Comment: @EdStevens, If i want to use built in feature, i have to depends on DBA's  totally, so to avoid DBA intervention , I've created the trigger.  After adding  'pragma autonomous transaction, its getting fired, but below values coming as NULL. 
    ora_dict_obj_owner,
      ora_dict_obj_type,
      ora_dict_obj_name,
      ora_sysevent

So any idea why above 4  values coming as NULL in 11g ? and can you let me know alternative for that ?

Thanks,
Vishnu

Comment: In my position as a DBA, I'd _welcome_ a developer asking me to help with using a built-in capability, rather than him writing his on sub-optimal solution that will not perform as well and very well could lead to additional operational problems.

Comment: "So to avoid DBA intervention" worst move you can make. Keep in mind that you and the DBA are both changed with producing the best system possible, It is only be working closely together that that is accomplished. BTW Unlike @EdStevens I am not a DBA.

Comment: @Belayer - - ""So to avoid DBA intervention" worst move you can make."  Couldn't have said it better myself.  Developers and DBA's need to be hand-in-glove with each other.  Just as DBA's also need to be hand-in-glove with their systems admins and network admins.